# Block Google Analytics IPs

Tags: firewall, google-analytics

I'm trying to block users in my network from accessing Google Analytics for some compliance reason. The only option is blocking by IP ranges right now. Is there a list of IP ranges that Google Analytics uses?

Specifically I'm trying to block HTTPS requests to www.google-analytics.com.

Is Google Analytics hosted on Google Cloud Platform? If that's the case, I can use https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#find_ip_range to just block all of GCP. It's a bit brute force, but should be OK for this use case.

But ideally there is a better way that will only block Google Analytics.

Comment: Is using the hosts file an option? https://geekthis.net/post/block-google-analytics/ You would need to somehow roll that out to the machines of the users, your question does not state if you have that option.

Comment: Or rather than `hosts`, if you control the network you control DNS. Make use of it. Super-easy to circumvent but that’s acceptable I guess.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use hosts file as it has to be external to the system, and I can't control DNS.

Comment: Then it’s not possible. Sorry. Blocking IPs will cause too much collateral damage. See Russia’s attempt to block Telegram.

Comment: I'm more than ok with collateral damage on this one. Silly requirements require silly solutions.